# How to set parameters in javascript navigator.sendBeacon()

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, beacon

I am trying to set the [credentials-mode](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-credentials-mode) param of this beacon request but have not find any useful content on the web to deal with it. Here is my code :

```
var sendBeacon = function (url, query_params, data) {
    var full_url = url + query_params;
    // Add Content Type JSON to beacon data
    var jsonBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'});
    var successTransfer = navigator.sendBeacon(full_url, jsonBlob);
 }
```

Any chance someone knows how to do it?